# Knockout binding not getting updated on jquery plugin event

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-plugins

I am trying to update a knockout binding on style { background-image: someobservable } when I crop the image using cropit but it's not working.

```
<div id="image-cropper">
    <!-- This is where the preview image is displayed -->
    <div class="cropit-image-preview" style="width:300px;height:170px;" data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(\'' + cropitImage() + '\')' }"></div>

    <!-- This range input controls zoom -->
    <!-- You can add additional elements here, e.g. the image icons -->
    <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input" />

    <!-- This is where user selects new image -->
    <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input" />

    <!-- The cropit- classes above are needed
    so cropit can identify these elements -->

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#image-cropper').cropit();
});
```

When I use the slider to crop the image it is updating the background image property of the div within style but when I check the value of the observable (cropitImage()) its not updating.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Relevant code seems to be missing. How is your observable defined, and what code is relevant for updating it? It's not really possible to spot the problem just from the code you posted so far.

Comment: I just have self.cropitImage = ko.observable(); in my view model. Wouldn't it update automatically if the backgroundImage property changes when I move the slider?

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work that way. I think that you need a custom binding for what you are trying to achieve. The cropit-plugin needs to be tied into your Knockout by hand. Knockout has no way of knowing that cropit changed the background image, so it won't update your observable. A custom binding can be used to fix that: your custom binding needs to know when cropit changes the image (probably using some event that cropit fires) and manually write the new value into your observable. For examples see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, custom bindings did the trick.

But it was not the usual implementation of it.

We usually use custom bindings so that, when an observable changes, update an associated DOM element.

But my requirement was --- When the user performs some action on a DOM element, update an associated observable.

Here's the code

```
ko.bindingHandlers.getImage = {

    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $('#image-cropper').on('change', function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var image = $('#image-cropper').cropit('export', {
                type: 'image/jpeg',
                quality: .7,
                originalSize: true
            });
            value(image);
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {     
        $('#image-cropper').on('change', function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            //var image = $('#image-cropper').cropit('export');
            var image = $('#image-cropper').cropit('export', {
                type: 'image/jpeg',
                quality: .9,
                originalSize: false
            });
            value(image);
        });
        $('#imgPreview').mouseup( function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            //var image = $('#image-cropper').cropit('export');
            var image = $('#image-cropper').cropit('export', {
                type: 'image/jpeg',
                quality: .9,
                originalSize: false
            });
            value(image);
        });
    }
};
```